# Extract Date from DateTime in U-SQL

Tags: u-sql

How to extract date from datetime in U-SQL as there is no inbuilt function for it like SQL. Please find below my code

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS dbo.Para AS
EXTRACT Statements

 FROM "/FileName.csv"
    USING Extractors.Csv(quoting : true, nullEscape : "/N");    

@ABC =
    SELECT (createdOn).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") AS Date
    FROM Para;

OUTPUT @ABC
TO "/date.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your code looks ok, does it work for you?  There is no `date` datatype in U-SQL so what you are doing should be fine.  See the [U-SQL Programmability Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-u-sql-programmability-guide) for more examples.

Comment: I want to take month/Year value from DateTime value from a column. I am using that value in the where condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that U-SQL Types are .Net/C# datatypes that give you all the methods available to them in .Net (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx).

So you can extract the date from datetime with:

```
@ABC =
    SELECT createdOn.Date AS Date
    FROM Parameter;
```

As an aside: Why are you specifying a view? Unless you want to register the view for later reuse in other scripts, you can just give the EXTRACT expression a name. E.g.,

```
@input = EXTRACT ....
```